# Issue with local storage element send in http post

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic2

I have issue with sending local storage element in http post request. it works with android and website but in ios http request being executed before getting local storage element. I have used async and await but i don't konow why this problem in ios only. here is code what i did.

```
async rpibuttonsselect(): Promise<rpibuttondataList[]> {
      const username = await this.storage.get('name');
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      var options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      let response = await this.http.post('http://node.services.com:3084/api/rpibuttonsselect/', JSON.stringify({ username: username }), options).toPromise();
      return response.json() as rpibuttondataList[];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the storage promise by using .then function and shoot the http request from that function.

```
      this.storage.get('name').then((username)=>{
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      var options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      let response = this.http.post('http://node.services.com:3084/api/rpibuttonsselect/', JSON.stringify({ username: username }), options);
    })
```

Comment: i can not use observable to subscribe response how can i do that  i tried something like this but i can not use subscribe method 
                                                                                                   
     `rpichart(){
    this.storage.get('name').then((username) => {
      ................
    })
  }`

Comment: I did something like this works in android but not work in ios application                                                            `rpichart() {
    return this.storage.get('name').then((username) => {
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      var options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      return this.http.post('http://node.futures-services.com:3084/api/rpichart/', JSON.stringify({ username: username }), options).map(res => res.json()).toPromise()
    });
  }`

Comment: did you get any error message? see the network in developer tools

Comment: My server crashes with can not read property something because i need to execute query in back end based on that username getting from storage